# Problema con bucle en IF

Tags: java, android-studio

me encuentro bloqueado en este punto, tengo un **IF** simple con dos condiciones, si el valor de un edittext `"123456789"'\n'"22335566"'\n'` ( **antes del salto de línea** ) es menor a "8"(valor de prueba)  y mayor de "14"(valor de prueba) emite un sonido, esta parte la tengo clara.

El problema lo tengo en que no soy capaz de contar los dígitos de cada línea, siempre me los acaba sumando al anterior no soy capaz de poner a 0 el contador de caracteres al saltar a otra línea, esto es lo que tengo

```
   @Override
public boolean onKeyUP(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    EditText text = (EditText)findViewById( R.id.etEdad );  // códigos de barra del editText 
    String stext = text.getText().toString();
    mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.error);
    final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.error);

    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
        //Log.i("BACK BUTTON ", "BACK BUTTON");

        return true;
    }
    Log.i("SCAN BUTTON ", "SCAN BUTTON");  // NO ES KEYCODE_ENTER  SINO   KEYCODE_SCAN  

    if(text.length()<8 || text.length()>14){
        Toast.makeText(this, "codigo: "+stext + "NO VALIDO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   // código de barras leido si da error 
        Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,"Num: "+text.length(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();  // LA 1ª LECTURA ES "0" Y LUEGO SUMA
        mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.error);
        MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.error);
        mp3.start();
        text.setText("");
    }

   return super.onKeyUp(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: Hola no se entiende bien lo que deseas realizar, ¿Esto es lo que tienes dentro de tu EditText "123456789"'\n'"22335566"'\n' ?¿Deseas contar primero "123456789" y después '"22335566" ?

Comment: Buenas, intentaré explicarme mejor, tengo una PDA con escaner laser, al pulsar el botón de escaneo lee un código de barras que aparece en el EditText cada código puede tener entre 9 o 14 dígitos todo lo que sea inferior o superior debe emitir un sonido para que la persona se de cuenta, por eso necesito comprobar en cada salto de línea la cantidad de caracteres.

Comment: OK @Roberto  debes realizar un bucle para revisar cada código, de hecho puedes imprimir en el TextView los que sin validos para que el usuario se de cuenta cuales ingresaron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hazle un split al texto que obtienes de tu EditText para que separe las lineas entre cada salto de linea y luego ya haces la comparación de la longitud.

```
String lineas[] = stext.split("\n");

if(lineas[0].length()<8 || lineas[0].length()>14 ||
    lineas[1].length()<8 || lineas[1].length()>14){
    //..Toast..
}
```

Para multiples lineas utiliza este código:

```
String[] lineas = stext.split("\n");

for(String linea : lineas){
    if(linea.length()<8 || linea.length()>14){
        //Toast                
    }
}
```

Comment: No es lo que busco porque solo me sirve para dos lecturas (saltos de línea), necesitaría en vez de [0], [1] un contador [i] creo, pero aún así si el primer código que leo es correcto tiene entre 8 y 13 caracteres me cierra la aplicación  java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=1; index=1

Comment: @Roberto Modifiqué la respuesta para que haga la verificación con multiples saltos de linea. ¿En qué linea te muestra el ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

Comment: Muchas gracias, con esto ya me vale.

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes realizar de esta forma, creando un bucle a partir de los códigos almacenados en un array generado por .split().

```
    String[] codigos = text.split("\n");

    //Bucle para revisar los códigos:
    for(String codigo :codigos){

        if(codigo.length()<8 || codigo.length()>14){
            Toast.makeText(this, "codigo: "+codigo + "NO VALIDO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   // código de barras leido si da error
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,"Num: "+text.length(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();  // LA 1ª LECTURA ES "0" Y LUEGO SUMA
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.error);
            MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.error);
            mp3.start();
            text.setText("");
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "codigo: "+codigo + "ES VALIDO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   // código de barras leido si da error
        }
    }
```

Puedes incluso mostrar en tu TextView únicamente los válidos:

```
    //Vacia textView
    text.setText("");

    String[] codigos = text.split("\n");

    //Bucle para revisar los códigos:
    for(String codigo :codigos){

        if(codigo.length()<8 || codigo.length()>14){
            Toast.makeText(this, "codigo: "+codigo + "NO VALIDO", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   // código de barras leido si da error
            Toast.makeText( MainActivity.this,"Num: "+text.length(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();  // LA 1ª LECTURA ES "0" Y LUEGO SUMA
            mMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.error);
            MediaPlayer mp3 = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.error);
            mp3.start();
            //text.setText("");
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this, "codigo: "+codigo + "ES VALIDO!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();   // código de barras leido si da error
           //Agrega a TextView código valido.
           text.setText(codigo + " " + text.getText());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gracias, también está muy bien